# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pythoncom'

Tags: python

I have already installed pywin32 package, the python file is working fine.
But when I unpack this file(used py2exe) and run the program, there is a error "**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pythoncom'**".

I also tried below ways, but still not solve.

1. import pythoncom at the python file.
2. copy these files from 'C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32' to C:\Windows\System32\pythoncom39.dll, pywintypes39.dll.
3. add options to setup `file(options={'py2exe': {"includes": ['pythoncom', 'lxml._elementpath', 'win32com', 'pywintypes']}})`

error message:
D:\XXX\dist>XXX.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "readExcel_sendMail.py", line 4, in 
File "", line 259, in load_module
File "win32com_*init*_.pyc", line 6, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pythoncom'

What's more, I found the dist folder have 'pythoncom39.dll' file, I don't know why it have this error.
how can I fix?

When I import win32com, the exe file will get the error.
eg):

```
import win32com.client as win32


def send_mail():
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')

    mail_item = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail_item.Recipients.Add('XXX@xx.com;')
    mail_item.Subject = 'Mail Test'

    mail_item.Send()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    send_mail()
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to do. Please provide the code to reproduce the `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Comment: when I import win32com in my python file, the exe file will get the error.
eg):
import win32com.client as win32


def send_mail():
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')

    mail_item = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail_item.Recipients.Add('XXX@xx.com;')
    mail_item.Subject = 'Mail Test'

    mail_item.Send()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    send_mail()

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

or

```
pip3 install pypiwin32
```

Comment: pip3 install pypiwin32 still unsolve this issue.